# How to map a function to every item in every sublist of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Is there a way to do this without using a regular for loop to iterate through the main list?

```
>>> map(lambda x: x*2, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]]
# want [[2,4,6],[8,10,12]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have nested lists, and `x` represents just one of the lists. To process that, you need to actually map the multiplication function on to the individual elements of `x`, like this

```
>>> map(lambda x: map(lambda y: y * 2, x), [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12]]
```

But I would prefer list comprehension over this,

```
>>> [[y * 2 for y in x] for x in [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution would be to go for numpy vectorized operations:

```
import numpy as np

ll = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

(2*np.array(ll)).tolist()
#Out[6]: [[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit overkill and not too practical for this particular example, but another stylistic option could be to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make it very clear what is happening and a combination of `map` and a list comprehension.

```
from functools import partial
from operator import mul

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

double = partial(mul, 2)
dub_l = [map(double, sub) for sub in l]
```